# Biological terminology: "codes for" vs. "codes a"

Tags: terminology, genetic-code

Maybe this is answered already before, but I cannot find it:

Most authors say/write "a gene codes *for* a protein", some use "a gene codes *a* protein". The latter seems to me the grammatically correct use of the verb "code".

What's the reason for saying "code for"? Is it because of RNA processing (e.g. splicing)? What about the coding of single amino acid: "AAA codes Lysin" or "AAA codes for Lysin"?
I would also like to know some history of the use of these (and may be other) terminologies.

Tia Udo

Comment: In the second usage ("a gene codes a protein"), it's likely the authors meant to write, "a gene encodes a protein". That would then be grammatically correct and correct phrasing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on SE English Language & Usage (especially the history part), but the poster would need to do some research first.

Comment: @DevonRyan "encode" is just the term I've found on Jennifer Doudna's talk.This question may be closed...

Answer (score 1):

This is an English usage question more than one of biology.  The verb *code* has two main meanings(1):

- (*transitive*) to put into the symbols of a code
- (*intransitive*) to be a code symbol

The first, which being transitive takes an [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)), is used for the act (as by a person) of translating a plain message into a corresponding encoded form. This is not the meaning used in "AAG codes for lysine".

The second form does not take an object.  It is not being done to something, but rather is just a state of being.  This form is almost always followed by a prepositional phrase "for *noun*", as in "INS codes for insulin".

Hence it is not correct English to say things like "INS codes insulin", as the use of "insulin" as an object implies the first meaning, as if one were saying "INS takes an insulin molecule and puts it into an encoded form" (whatever that would mean).

The reader would likely try to interpret "INS codes insulin" with the intended meaning, but the incorrect usage makes it seem equivalent to something like "INS is a DNA sequence insulin."  Leaving out the preposition *for* may be shorter, but it gives a bumpier ride.

(1): [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coded).  For more variants see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code#Verb), esp. [*encode*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encode#Verb).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I agree with the intransitive form "be a code for", e.g. "Gene G is a code for Protein P". I've put that question on (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416263/general-examples-of-to-code-for) to get examples of non-genetics usage of "code for". btw: I'm just watching a video of Jennifer Doudna, which is an expert in the field of genetics, and she uses "Gene G encodes Protein P" which look very fine to mee (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuAxDVBt7kQ?t=254)

Comment: I couldn't edit the last comment since it was older than 5 mins:
... I've read Merriam-Webster's and Wiktionary's articles and agree with the intransitive form "be a code for", e.g. "Gene G is a code for Protein P".
I've put that question on (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416263/general-examples-of-to-code-for) to get examples of non-genetics usages of "code for".
btw: I'm just watching a video of Jennifer Doudna, which is an expert in the field of genetics, and she uses "Gene G encodes Protein P" which looks very fine to me (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuAxDVBt7kQ?t=254)